How to use Python map to produce multiple values for each original input
I have a list of data structure that looks like this:
Class Event:
   start: datetime
   end: datetime

Take a list[Event], I want to produce a new list that have two entries for each original Event:
event_a = Event(start=2024-06-14, end=2024-06-15)
event_b = Event(start=2024-07-14, end=2024-07-15)

input_list = [event_a, event_b]

# construct new list here
def construct(input_list: list[Event]) -> list[datetime]:
   ...

output_list = construct(input_list)

# expected output is
# [2024-06-14, 2024-06-15, 2024-07-14, 2024-07-15]

I know I can do it with list comprehension and I'm wondering can I do it efficiently with a map.
I've tried:
output_list = map(lambda x: (x.start, x.end), input_list)

but this returns
[(2024-06-14, 2024-06-15), (2024-07-14, 2024-07-15)]

Is there a way I can tweak the map lambda that directly return a flatten list instead?

No, Assuming this is python 3.x, map returns an iterable that emits one value per item iterated, not the entire list. You need to do the flattening outside of map. output_list = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: (x.start, x.end), input_list)))

Or sum(map(lambda x: [x.start, x.end], input_list), [])

@e-motta: Good lord, not that. Using sum that was makes it a quadratic function. If you really hate itertools.chain, from functools import reduce, from operator import iconcat, and using reduce(iconcat, map(lambda x: (x.start, x.end), input_list), []) would achieve the result you're going for efficiently (producing cheap two-tuples as intermediate values, and using amortized growth of a single list rather than building bigger and bigger lists, discarding the last one each time, for each new pair of values).

@ShadowRanger I'd rather use a list comprehension, tbh. None of these options answer the question though, so there's that too.

@e-motta: Agreed. If you need a lambda to use map/filter, then just use a listcomp or genexpr instead. [pos for x in input_list for pos in (x.start, x.end)] involves no imports and is pretty efficient. If it's really a perf bottleneck, you can look at using from operator import attrgetter, iconcat and reduce(iconcat, map(attrgetter('start', 'end'), input_list), []) (which drops the last lambda, pushes all the work to the C layer and might outperform the listcomp), but that involves two imports and some rather more complex code, that's usually not worth it.

@e-motta Don't use sum to concatenate lists, that's a classic anti-pattern

@ShadowRanger I doubt it will outperform significantly because you still get the function call overhead for each iteration, making it a wash, if I had to bet.

@juanpa.arrivillaga: So admission: I knew it would outperform from prior testing, just didn't remember by how much. On my local machine (for simple list of tuples, avoiding map+operator.attrgetter as more complexity), IPython on 3.12 microbenchmarks with setup inp = [(i,i) for i in range(10000)]; from functools import reduce; from operator import iconcat, comparing reduce(iconcat, inp, []) to [i for x in inp for i in x], the listcomp reliably takes about 40% longer than the reduce+iconcat solution. [*chain.from_iterable(inp)] is in-between, at ~22% longer than reduce.

@ShadowRanger yeah, I guess that iteration is so expensive at the interpreter level, and even chain.from_iterable (which would still be my preferred solution) still needs to go through the whole protocol.

@ShadowRanger, e-motta thank you guys for the suggestions really appreciate it!
I also did some experiment and get similar results as you did. On my local with Python 3.12.2, map+itertools save ~40% compare with list iteration. I'm a bit leaning towards efficiency here as I can adopt the pattern elsewhere.

The combination of operator.attrgetter and itertools.chain.from_iterable can do the job. Since it doesn't call a pure python function in a loop(like lambda), it may be faster I guess:
from datetime import datetime
from itertools import chain
from operator import attrgetter


class Event:
    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end


def construct(input_list: list[Event]) -> list[datetime]:
    f = attrgetter("start", "end")
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(f, input_list)))


event_a = Event(start="2024-06-14", end="2024-06-15")
event_b = Event(start="2024-07-14", end="2024-07-15")

print(construct([event_a, event_b]))

Note: You can also use "slots" for the Event objects. The attribute access would be faster.

If you're willing to use a package, you can look at more_itertools.collapse! Then your could would look like
output_list = more_itertools.collapse(map(lambda x: (x.start, x.end), input_list))

Credit to this SO answer

Yes, we can use map and lambda along side the itertools library that comes built in with Python to do this.
from itertools import chain

def construct(input_list: list[Event]) -> list[datetime]:
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(lambda x: [x.start.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), x.end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')], input_list)))

We just need to provide construct with a list of your event class like:
event_a = Event(start=datetime(2024, 6, 14), end=datetime(2024, 6, 15))
event_b = Event(start=datetime(2024, 7, 14), end=datetime(2024, 7, 15))

input_list = [event_a, event_b]
output_list = construct(input_list)

and output list should be a flattened array of dates in the form
['2024-06-14', '2024-06-15', '2024-07-14', '2024-07-15']


Here is an approach which do not use any library and also easy to understand:
def construct(events: list[Event]) -> list:
    out = []
    for event in events:
        out.append(event.start)
        out.append(event.end)
    return out

